# How to record data send along api request on Google Cloud Platform

Tags: rest, api, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I am trying to find a way to store or record the (json) data that is send with an API request from a client side.

I set up an API for a model via Google Kubernetes Engine in the Google Cloud Platform.

As an example, let's say the model is y = x + 2. If I send a request with data = 2, I get a response of 4; everything working fine. However, I wonder if I can log the fact that 'data = 2', was send to the API. If this is possible, how or where can I do this in the GCP?

Comment: Within the Google Cloud Platform (GCP), the service for writing log entries is called "Stackdriver Logging".   From the summary you provided, you would include Stackdriver logging API calls in the code that implements your processing.  You were vague on the nature of the logic.

Comment: You can refer [this link](https://cloud.google.com/logging/) about [Stackdriver logging](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/) to get more information. A detailed explanation on [how to reconfigure this Logging](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/how-to) with the help of agent or various programming language environments are explained [here](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/how-to) as well. I hope this helps.

Comment: What do you want to do with this logs? With which velocity do you need to process them?